# Skip a directory with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So i have this in my htaccess file to take care of the trailing slash problem . It redirects you every time you add a trailing slash on a url.

The issue here is the fact there is one directory where it needs the trailing slash or it breaks. How do I add a exception for a directory like http://www.example.com/com/ to this rule..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest to understand approach is to use an additional condition:

```
RewriteCond $1           !=com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works because the order of execution is rule.regexp, cond1, cond2, rule.substitution.  Hence the $1 variable is available to the (new) cond1. You could also use a negative assertion on your regexp.

Incidentally, the `http://%{HTTP_HOST}/` is assumed in the case of a [R=301] for http.  Why do you not want to remove `/` for other host aliases?